# C# delete multiple selection from datagridview using stored procedure pass the same cell value each time

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am using form1 which has datagridview which the user should select multiple row to delete using a stored procedure to delete the selected rows.

But the stored procedure gets the same value each time the user try to delete while its executed multiple times according to the rows count

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in gvhistorder.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()select row).ToList();

    if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Do you want to delete {0} rows?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = gvhistorder.SelectedRows;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
        {
            DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
            int order_num = (int)gvhistorder.SelectedRows[0].Cells["order_number"].Value;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DelHisOL", con);           
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter[] DelHistParm = new SqlParameter[3];
            DelHistParm[0] = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            DelHistParm[0].Value = OrderDate.Text;
            DelHistParm[1] = new SqlParameter("@store", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
            DelHistParm[1].Value = store.SelectedValue;
            DelHistParm[2] = new SqlParameter("@orderNum", SqlDbType.Int);
            DelHistParm[2].Value = order_num;

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(DelHistParm);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `@orderNum`: it gets the same value for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
 int order_num =(int) row.Cells["order_number"].Value;
```

Comment: Error:    Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)